# Can arguments be overwritten?

Tags: javascript

According to this [mozilla document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), the `arguments` can be set:

```
arguments[1] = 'new value';
```

But my `jshint` refuses to accept that. Can arguments be set or not?

This is what I have to do now:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('propPartial', function(property, options) {
    var name = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, property);
    // I have to do this because arguments[0] = name; does not work, contrary to what is stated here:
    //   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments
    var args = [], i, l;
    args.push(name);
    for (i = 1, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.partial.apply(this, args);
});
```

### UPDATE, for reference

Thanks to @TJCrowder, this is the working code, fooling `jshint`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('propPartial', function(property, options) {
    var name = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, property);
    var args = arguments;
    args[0] = name;
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.partial.apply(this, args);
});
```

Comment: Additional information: If you enable 'use strict', you are not allowed to do this and it will additionally throw an exception for it.

Comment: @KyorCode: You're allowed to do this in strict mode. You're not allowed to do `arguments = someOtherThing` (completely rebinding the `arguments` symbol), but you're still allowed to assign to its contents.

Comment: Note: If you want an `Array` from `arguments`, you can use `slice`: `var args = [name].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: I think you meant `slice(1)`. Or without creating and throwing away a temp array: `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); args[0] = name;`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: LOL Actually I realized the code in my answer above doesn't create and throw away any temp arrays. So I think it would be the most efficient solution for doing the copy and then updating the first arg. I wouldn't use `unshift` for this, too much work involved in renaming all those array element properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they can. There are *lots* of things you can do in JavaScript that JSLint has issues with.

I don't suggest it, but you *can* do it.

If you really, really want to do this and pass `jslint`, you can fool it:

```
var a = arguments;
a[1] = 'new value';
```

---

Note that the link between `arguments` and any named arguments in your function is *live* in loose mode. E.g.:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    arguments[1] = "x"; // This line changes `b`
    console.log("a = " + a);
    console.log("b = " + b);
}

foo(1, 2);
```

outputs

```
a = 1
b = x
```

In *strict* mode, though, they don't remain linked:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    "use strict";

    arguments[1] = "x"; // This line does *not* change `b`
    console.log("a = " + a);
    console.log("b = " + b);
}

foo(1, 2);
```

outputs

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Comment: Any idea how to tell jslint to be more permisive about that? I do not want spurious errors. My `jslint` output is clean now, and I would have to `-force`, which would be *very* bad.

Comment: @gonvaled: `jslint` is designed to be intolerant. Douglas Crockford is a very intelligent and well-informed man, but he *does* have strong opinions and encoded many of them in `jslint` as absolute rules. There's a fork, [`jshint`](http://www.jshint.com/) which has options for during things on and off. I don't immediately see one for what you're doing, but it may be there. The larger question would be: Why are you assigning to `arguments[1]`?

Comment: Well, to make a long story short: I am wrapping a handlebars helper, and I need to pass down the arguments passed to my wrapper, except the first argument, which must be mapped (that is the whole point of the wrapper, actually). The solution I am using now is to copy `arguments` to an array (except first element, which I map), and then passing the array as new `arguments`. This seems really bad style, and inefficient. Editted my question with my helper.

Comment: @gonvaled: I found a way to fool `jslint` without making the copy, see the update. Re your comment to rednaw asking why it's "bad", I can't speak for Crockford on that, but he *may* have been bothered by the hidden link to the formal arg (`jslint` originates well before strict mode) or by performance issues...

Comment: Actually, it turns out I am using `jshint`. The same trick you suggested works for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do that. JSLint is only a tool to check if the codes applies to some coding rules. These rules are created to stimulate writing good javascript code.

So you can use it, but it's not adviced, since it's concidered "bad" javascript code.

More info about JSLint: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

The reason I think JSLint doesn't allow this is because in general, a programmer would expect the `arguments` variable to contain the arguments passed to the function. If you manipulate this, you change the "reality" of the programmer.

You could maybe better assign it to another variable:

```
var my_argument = arguments[1] || 'fallback_value';
```

Comment: I am aware of what jslint is. What I do not know is what is the downside of modifying `arguments`. That is: why is it "bad" coding style?